# UIScene userActivity is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiscene

I have a (Catalyst) app, that is able to have several windows. I created a button and if the user presses this button, the app creates a new window. To know, what View needs to be shown, I have different `NSUserActivity` activityTypes. In the new window there should be a button, that can close this new window. The problem is, that on looping through the open sessions, all the userActivities are `nil` (and I need the correct `UISceneSession` for the `UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionDestruction`.

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Open window type 1
            Button(action: {
                UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation(nil,
                                                                   userActivity: NSUserActivity(activityType: "window1"),
                                                                   options: nil,
                                                                   errorHandler: nil)
            }) {
                Text("Open new window - Type 1")
            }

            // Open window type 2
            Button(action: {
                UIApplication.shared.requestSceneSessionActivation(nil,
                                                                   userActivity: NSUserActivity(activityType: "window2"),
                                                                   options: nil,
                                                                   errorHandler: nil)
            }) {
                Text("Open new window - Type 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

            if connectionOptions.userActivities.first?.activityType == "window1" {
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: Window1())
            } else if connectionOptions.userActivities.first?.activityType == "window2" {
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: Window2())
            } else {
                window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
            }
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
...
```

```
struct Window1: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Window1")
            Button("show") {
                for session in UIApplication.shared.openSessions {
                    // this prints two times nil !
                    print(session.scene?.userActivity?.activityType)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct Window2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Window2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I ended up assigning unique delegate classes to each scene and checking that instead.